# How to use random forests in R for classification to decide if the value of a column is less or greater than a value N?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I have already used random forests in R for classification where the concerned column has categorical values ( 0 or 1 for example). For example, for the iris database, we can use random forests to classify the data depending on the species as follows:

```
myRF <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,proximity=TRUE)
```

This makes sense because Species can take only a couple of categorical values. The question is what about if Species could take values from 1 to 100 and I wanted to classify the data into two categories: the ones where the value if greater than 50 and the ones where the value is less than 50?

Of course, I could add another column whose value is 1 or 0 depending on Species, and then I do classification on that last column instead of Species, but is there a way to tell R directly that we want to classify our data into 2 categories: a category where Species is less than 50 and another one where it is greater than 50? ( Assuming the new hypothetical values for Species)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myRf ~ randomForest(Species < 50 ~ ., ...)
```

which is

1. really no different to defining a new variable that contains whether `Species` is less than 50, but avoids modifying your dataset;
2. only sensible if `Species` is a continuous rather than categorical variable (ie, it makes sense to compare species numbers in this way).

In the more general case where you want to predict that a factor will take on one of a subset of values, you can use

```
randomForest(y.fac %in% c("level1","level2",...) ~ .....)
```